# Comparing current datetime with datetime from database without refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to make a simple reminder which displays something when the current date and time matches an entry in a database, without refreshing the page.

I have two entries in my database in a table called `date`:

- `date` (stores reminder date) which is type `DATE` and
- `time` (stores reminder time) which has type `TIME`.

The page `reminder.php` fetches the date and time stored in database and converts it into `Timestamp`.

This page also converts the current date and time into `Timestamp` using `strtotime("now")`.

It displays both date and time when both values match by continuously refreshing the page every second.

I want to compare both values without refreshing the `reminder.php` page.

**reminder.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'php/database.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$current = strtotime('now');
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM date");
$row = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $key) {
    $dateTime = $key['date'] . $key['time'];
    $dateTime  = strtotime($dateTime);

}

if ($dateTime == $current) {
    echo  "both date and time are same";
}
else {

    echo "both date and time are not same";

}
```

Comment: Return the data once from the page and insert it into your page JS, have the JS do the checking. If you really want, refresh it from the DB once every few minutes at most (to catch new items in the table). You can use ajax to grab the data from the page on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understands right then you need to check date from the database and current date without refreshing the page use this code ,
HTML Part :

```
<button id="data_pass" name="btn" >BUTTON</button>
```

JQuERy :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#data_pass").click(function() {
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
   dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
  mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

$.ajax({
url  : 'test.php',
type : 'post',
data : {"today":today},
success : function(data) {
    alert(data);                                        
},
error : function(data) {
    alert("error");
}


});

});
});
```

PHP Part :

```
  include('db_con.php');

   class date_check extends db_connection { 
   function dates() {
    $con    = $this->db_con();
    $sel    = $con->prepare("select * from dates");
    $exe    = $sel->execute();
    $dates  = $_POST['today'];
    foreach ($sel as $select) {
        if ($select['date_i'] == $dates) {
            echo "Happy BirthDay";  
        }   
    }
}


}

 $obj   = new date_check;
$obj->dates();
```

It's only for checking the date. 
hope it will help you

Comment: you mean current date and time ie,2015/07/29 10:10:00